# complex query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
 -table : events 
 [id=>1 , data_id =>1 , events_reference =>5 , g_id=>0
  id=>5  , data_id=>1 , events_reference =>NULL , g_id=>1,
  id=>6 . , data_id=>3, events_reference => 5 ,g_id=>0 ]

 - table : data
 [id=> 0 , name=>test1,
  id=>1 , name=>test2,
  id=>3 , name=>tes3 ]
```

I want to get column name g_id_1 including the data name if g_id_1 equal to data.id in data table(not the data_id column), and also I want to get column name g_id_2 that show the data name based on the events reference

ALSO, I want only bring the data that the data.id = 1 for example so event.id =6 will not appear

expected result: (get all events and + new columns calls "g_id_1" + "g_id_2")

```
{
 "id"=>1,
 events_reference => 5,
 "g_id_1" = > "test 1"
 "g_id_2" => "test 2"
},
{
 "id"=>5,
 events_reference => NULL,
 "g_id_1" = > "test 2" 
 "g_id_2" => NULL
}
```

How can I do that, I tried with sub select but I manage to get the first level but not the second level because the events_reference is reference to another row in the same table

```
select id,events_reference , (SELECT name from data as d where events.events_reference = d.id) as g_id_1, 
(SELECT name from data as d,events as e where e.events_reference = d.id) as g_id_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a mySQL wiz but pretty good is MSSQL and it looks like you are wanting to do a LEFT join.
So what that will do is return another table IF the data exists.

```
SELECT events.id, events.events_reference, data.g_id_1, data.g_id_2
FROM events
LEFT JOIN data ON events.events_reference = eventtable.events_reference
LEFT JOIN data data2 ON eventtable.g_id_2 = eventtable2.g_id_1;
```

Pretty sure that is what your asking for, let me know if its not and I will have another look.

Caz

Comment: There are only 2 tables in his question, not 3.

Comment: Where is the `data` table in your query?

Comment: He needs to join the same table twice in order to do the g_id_2 to g_id_1 lookup. There are not three tables but there are three joins.

Comment: You're missing one of the joins. See my answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to rejoin the event table, as the g_id_2 references the g_id_1 of the data table, you don't have a event ref so why join that table back in again?

Comment: You need to rejoin the `events` table to go from `event_reference` to that row's `g_id`.

Comment: Feel free to try running your query in my sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables. You need to use multiple joins of the same tables to get the nested references. And you have to use `LEFT JOIN` to handle the cases where there's no match.

```
SELECT e1.id, e1.events_reference, d1.name AS g_id_1, d2.name AS g_id_2
FROM events AS e1
LEFT JOIN data AS d1 ON e1.g_id = d1.id
LEFT JOIN events AS e2 ON e1.events_reference = e2.id
LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON e2.g_id = d2.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47116b/1)

Comment: HI thanks a lot its work ,but if there is a date in events table, i added order by date desc or asc and it is not working , why?

Comment: It needs to be `ORDER BY e1.date`. Otherwise the `date` column is ambiguous.

Comment: thanks . , another question. How can I make sure or envelope the SQL that the only rows with data.id = events.id will appears ? , so if i will add data.id = 8 to data.id table  and there is no data.id like that in the events.table it will not take it

Comment: I updated my question I also take only where data.id = X . but if I added where its not working

Comment: I don't understand. If you only want `data.id = 1`, why does your result include `g_id_1 = test1`? That has `data.id = 0`